# I'm looking for a very specific Birkat Hamazon tune

Tags: music, bentching

As the title says, I'm looking for a Birkat Hamazon tune that I know through my family but have never heard from anyone else. I've heard it on a record from the Brandeis-Bardin Institute from the 1950s, but haven't been able to find it anywhere on the web. My family talks about it coming from the Brandeis-Bardin Institute and hearing it at the Bnai Brith Perlman Camp in the late 1950s.

I've asked around but haven't been able to find anyone else who recognizes the tune. If anyone else has any clue what I'm talking about or knows anything that might help me on my quest to find this tune, please let me know!

Thanks!

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: Which part of bircas hamazon?

Comment: Can you sing it and want to identify its provenance? Or you don't even know how it goes?

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean the one that appears here:
https://www.facebook.com/reel/1623628751440239

Max Helfman was Brandeis-Bardin and Camp Alonim’s first music director. Helfman, already an accomplished musician, composer, and choir-director, became a central component of the camp formula from 1944 on. Dr. Bardin was extremely impressed with Helfman’s ability to connect with the students, remarking how he “radiated enthusiasm” and became “the soul of camp.” Helfman left an indelible imprint, not only through his role as music director, but also through his talents as a composer. He created new melodies specifically for camp. Bardin and Helfman decided not to use melodies traditionally associated with the Reform, Conservative, or Orthodox movements, a decision that helped keep camp nonsectarian. In addition, by using brand-new melodies composed by Helfman himself, and sung at Alonim to this day, they ensured that all participants would be on an even playing field. You can listen to Helfman’s Birkat Hamazon in the video above, which is still sung in full each Friday evening after Shabbat dinner at Alonim.

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Motty and thanks for this first answer. Great to have you learn with us!